i get path in my flutter using Directory but i not found correct path
in the Flutter app, I get the path in my Flutter project using Directory but I have not found the correct path
file path:- /data/user/0/com.xyz.app/app_flutter/file_name.xls I can not find this type of path in my physical device. find the right way of path. and given path details explanation
